# Regex (or other solution) to get all words in string, including emoticons, and stripped punctuations

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, string-parsing

For example:

```
Hello! :)  It's a good day to-day :D  'Aight? <3
```

It would return:

1. Hello
2. :)
3. It's
4. a
5. good
6. day
7. to-day
8. :D
9. 'Aight
10. <3

One may consider all emoticons to be two characters long...also, if it helps, only 'forwards' emoticons would probably be encountered.

The case without emoticons is trivial, but with them -- as well as stripping out punctuation of other words -- is sort of tripping me up.

Is there an quick way besides .split and running a block to check each word logically?

Comment: Splitting and examining seems like a good solution to me.

Comment: Also, please include the code you already have so we can help improve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex should find any words (without punctuation other than a dash/single-quote/underscore), or a 2-character emoticon:

```
\s*(?:([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\']+)|([\:\;\=\[\]\{\}\(\)\<3dDpP]{2}))\s*
```

Regex Explained:

```
\s*                             # any whitespace
(?:
    ([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\']+)        # any alpha-numeric character, dashes, underscores, single-quotes
    |
    ([\:\;\=\[\]\{\}\(\)\<3dDpP]{2})    # any 2-punctuation marks commonly found in emoticons, including
                                # the number 3, for the <3 and D for :D
)
\s*                             # any whitespace
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not actually a regex, but does the job!

```
"Hello! :)  It's a good day to-day :D  'Aight? <3".split
=> ["Hello!", ":)", "It's", "a", "good", "day", "to-day", ":D", "'Aight?", "<3"]
```

Comment: You'd need to strip the punctuation as well.

Comment: The first word is desired to be "Hello", without the exclamation.